# ReactiveUI RaiseAndSetIfChanged() Backing Field Accesibility

Tags: c#, silverlight, properties, system.reactive, reactiveui

Problem: Cannot set backing field of property to `private` as I get the following exception when setting a value to `Name`.

```
System.ArgumentException : You must declare a 
backing field for this property named: _Name
```

My Code:

```
public class MyVM : ReactiveObject
{
    private string _Name;
    public string Name
    {
        get { return _Name; }

        set { this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(x => x.Name, value); }
    }
}
```

To Fix this i have been able to set _Name to public:

```
    public string _Name;
```

Which fixed the problem, but why do I have to expose the backing field as public? The examples I see on the Net use private backing fields...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the new overload instead, unless you're not using >= VS2012:

```
this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref theBackingField, value);
```

Comment: Thanks!!! Worked perfectly! Great job on System.Reactive and ReactiveUI!!!Tried googling for this but couldn't find it anywhere! :D